# How to remove Elasticsearch from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I think that I already removed elasticsearch from my computer, and still I have some doubts.

When I type:

```
$ service elasticsearch status
```

I get:

> elasticsearch.service    Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or
>   directory)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-08-09
>   01:08:18 PDT; 38min ago  Main PID: 73249 (code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Aug 09 01:08:18 ubuntu elasticsearch[73249]: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000085330000,
>   2060255232, 0) fai Aug 09 01:08:18 ubuntu elasticsearch[73249]: # Aug
>   09 01:08:18 ubuntu elasticsearch[73249]: # There is insufficient
>   memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. Aug 09 01:08:18
>   ubuntu elasticsearch[73249]: # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed
>   to map 2060255232 bytes for committing reserved memory. Aug 09
>   01:08:18 ubuntu elasticsearch[73249]: # An error report file with more
>   information is saved as: Aug 09 01:08:18 ubuntu elasticsearch[73249]:
>
> ## /tmp/hs_err_pid73249.log Aug 09 01:08:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited,
>
> status=1/FAILURE Aug 09 01:08:18 ubuntu systemd[1]:
>   elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state. Aug 09 01:08:18
>   ubuntu systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result
>   'exit-code'. Aug 09 01:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Elasticsearch.

However, when I type:

```
$ service helloworld status
```

I get somehting much shorter:

> helloworld.service    Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or
>
> directory)    Active: inactive (dead)

I already removed Elasticsearch by using the command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove elasticsearch
```

and it still looks like elasticsearch exists.

Comment: check this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-completely-uninstall-elasticsearch/35832 you might have forgotten to remove the service script /etc/init.d/elasticsearch

Comment: I read it. I got: 
find: unknown predicate `--name'

Comment: that an error in the syntax of the `find` command and isn't related to elasticsearch. Try with locate as explained in my answer below.

Comment: Here is a discussion around the `find` error you are having:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/142207/find-unknown-predicate

Answer (score 37):

On ubuntu 20.04, I had a similar problem: I wanted to totally remove  elasticsearch 7.15.1 and install the previous version 7.10.1.

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge elasticsearch
```

The message was:

```
dpkg: warning: while removing elasticsearch, directory '/var/lib/elasticsearch' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing elasticsearch, directory '/etc/elasticsearch' not empty so not removed
```

So I removed those directories:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/elasticsearch
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/elasticsearch
```

And I was able to downgrade without any errors:

```
sudo apt-get install elasticsearch=7.10.1
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
curl http://localhost:9200/
```

Answer (score 14):

for uninstall deb package you can use:

```
dpkg --purge elasticsearch
```

or

```
apt-get --purge autoremove elasticsearch
```

you can find all elasticsearch related folders with `locate elasticsearch` but before that use `updatedb` command.

```
# updatedb

# locate elasticsearch
```

I will list all default elasticsearch path for more information.

configurations files:

```
/etc/elasticsearch/
/etc/default/elasticsearch
```

base path(bins and libs and ...):

```
/usr/share/elasticsearch/
```

data path (can be configured in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml):

```
/var/lib/elasticsearch
```

log path (can be configured in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml):

```
/var/log/elasticsearch/
```

service files:

```
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/elasticsearch.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the startup script for elasticsearch `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` has been left behind after the uninstallation. So, remove it and should be the final step.

You can also try to locate if there are any other left scripts, files or folders using the following command:

```
# locate elasticsearch
```

And then remove those as explained in elastic forums [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-completely-uninstall-elasticsearch/35832/3).

Notice that to enable `locate` to look everywhere you need to launch the command as root.

Comment: ls: cannot access '/etc/init.d/elasticsearch': No such file or directory and I still get the error that elasticsearch FAILED and not (NOT FOUND)