# Elasticsearch 7.10 : How to safely remove a node and free up space?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-7

As I am running out of my disk space, I want to remove all the indices from the node. Note that I have just one node, and I am running the elastic server on my local machine.

Basically, when I start the elastic server, it fails with the following log -

```
[2020-12-13T22:06:51,839][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [sedna] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [k7t835EJQ6KzPu-7a-aW8Q][sedna][/home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/data/nodes/0] free: 879mb[0.8%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
```

While on the terminal I get the following error -

```
Could not rename log file 'logs/gc.log' to 'logs/gc.log.05' (Reserved).
(base) ssahoo@sedna:~/elasticsearch-7.10.0$ [2020-12-14T17:07:17,831][WARN ][stderr                   ] [sedna] Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapException: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
2020-12-14 17:07:17,848 main ERROR Unable to move file /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch_server.json to /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch-2020-12-13-1.json: java.nio.file.FileSystemException /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch_server.json -> /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch-2020-12-13-1.json: Disk quota exceeded
2020-12-14 17:07:17,852 main ERROR Unable to copy file /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch_server.json to /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch-2020-12-13-1.json: java.nio.file.FileSystemException /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch-2020-12-13-1.json: Disk quota exceeded
2020-12-14 17:07:17,857 main ERROR Unable to move file /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch.log to /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch-2020-12-13-1.log: java.nio.file.FileSystemException /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch.log -> /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch-2020-12-13-1.log: Disk quota exceeded
2020-12-14 17:07:17,861 main ERROR Unable to copy file /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch.log to /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch-2020-12-13-1.log: java.nio.file.FileSystemException /home/ssahoo/elasticsearch-7.10.0/logs/elasticsearch-2020-12-13-1.log: Disk quota exceeded
[2020-12-14T17:07:17,863][WARN ][stderr                   ] [sedna] Likely root cause: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
[2020-12-14T17:07:17,864][WARN ][stderr                   ] [sedna]     at java.base/java.io.FileDescriptor.close0(Native Method)
[2020-12-14T17:07:17,864][WARN ][stderr                   ] [sedna]     at java.base/java.io.FileDescriptor.close(FileDescriptor.java:297)
```

Therefore I want to free up space by removing all the indices, and therefore the node. So how can I remove the single node that I have?

Or if may I ask what would your suggestion be to overcome this? I can't afford additional disk space and is my major constraint.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to remove the node, why don't you just unistall it ? datas of elastic are in a Data folder. so it's pretty easy to just remove everything. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/setup-dir-layout.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585881/how-to-remove-elasticsearch-from-ubuntu/64682271#64682271

Comment: But then I need to use elastic search for my later usage, and therefore I need to re-install it all over again.

Comment: Is there no other safe way to remove the node as I don't need the old indices any longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to remove all the indices from the node

In order to remove `all` indices from a node, get the list of indices and then call `delete` on each.

E.g.

```
for i in $(curl -s -u user:password -XGET "<your_es_host_name>:9200/_cat/indices?s=index&h=index"); do echo "deleting Index --> $i"; curl -s -u user:password -XDELETE "< your_es_host_name>:9200/$i"; done
```

This will delete all your indices. If you want to exclude certain indices, you can modify the code to exclude indices like `"<your_es_host_name>:9200/_cat/indices?s=index&h=index | grep -v exclude_index"`.

Hope this helps.